# Why does avconv not work to record my screen?

Tags: avconv

I am trying to record my screen (without sound) using avconv but i think there is something wrong with it.

I gave the command

```
  avconv -f x11grab -s hd720 -r 30 -i 0:0  sample.mov
```

it ends up with an error

```
 [x11grab @ 0x84c03c0] device: 0:0 -> display: 0:0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1280 height: 720
 No protocol specified
 [x11grab @ 0x84c03c0] Could not open X display.
 0:0: Input/output error
```

Am i doing something wrong if, please tell me the solution

Comment: How are you running this command? In a terminal window in your desktop environment or via SSH? Are you the same user as the X session is running as? And what does `echo $DISPLAY` give you?

Comment: i am running it through terminal

Comment: when i give the command with the first user ( created when installing ubuntu ) it works but on the second user ( created after install ubuntu ) it gives me the error  @gertvdijk

Comment: Have you tried "-i $DISPLAY" instead of "-i 0:0"? Btw: What is the output of: echo $DISPLAY ?

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is one missing `:` and `.`

In your command where you specifiy the display `-i 0:0`

> avconv -f x11grab -s hd720 -r 30 -i 0:0  sample.mov

It should be `-i :0.0`

> avconv -f x11grab -s hd720 -r 30 -i :0.0  sample.mov

You can always double check by looking at your environmental variable for display in your terminal.

> echo $DISPLAY
>   :0.0

To understand what the display variable means have look at this post. 
https://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/xterminal/xclients.php

> -display hostname:n.m
>
> Where hostname is the network hostname, qualified with domain name as
>   needed (or use the IP address directly); n is the display number on
>   that host (usually 0); and m is the screen number on that host
>   (usually 0). For example, if you am logged into the console on the
>   workstation eluard and want to run the xload client on pangea with the
>   output window coming back to eluard, you could start this program on
>   pangea with the option:
>
> xload -display eluard:0.0
>
> localhost is assumed if the hostname is omitted `localhost:0.0` is the same as `:0.0`